# XSLT whitespace bewteen text runs divides word

Tags: xslt, whitespace

I have a docx file where I've written "Name Surname". When I transform it I get "Name Sur name." In the xml of the docx the surname has been divided into two different text runs. Both of them have the same `w:rsidRPr`, `w:rPr`, `w:sz`and `w:szCs`. They are different exclusively in that the second test run has `w:rsidR` and also that `w:t` has the `xml:space="preserve"` argument. I include a full example but apologize for it runnning off the screen.

In docx:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="0088058E" w:rsidRDefault="0088058E" w:rsidP="00556F45"><w:pPr><w:spacing w:line="480" w:lineRule="auto"/><w:rPr><w:b/><w:sz w:val="28"/><w:szCs w:val="28"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00556F96"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t> Name Sur</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="004C22E6" w:rsidRPr="00556F96"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">name.</w:t></w:r></w:p>
```

In the transformed xml output: `<p><hi>Name Sur</hi><hi>name</hi></p>`

In the stylesheet that I'm using to transform this docx I deal with whitespace like this:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="w:t"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
```

What sort of exception or override can I write so that the transform doesn't have a whitespace within surname?

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example. You're not showing us your transformation, not the expected result. And your input example is not well-formed XML. See; [mcve]

Comment: @JimGarrison Please don't edit OP's code - esp. not when the question is about whitespace.

Comment: edited as per @michael.hor257k recommendation. First question in SO, I appreciate any comments as to how to improve it.

Comment: I am afraid you don't understand what a reproducible example means. We need to see code that we can run **as is** (doing nothing but copy and paste) and receive the result you claim. -- Note also that the result you show us has no space between "Sur" and "name" - so it's not at all clear what your complaint is.

Comment: I apologize for having failed to provide reproducible code. I'm new to xslt and I'm working with a very complex variation on [docxtotei](http://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-xsl/profiles/default/docx/from1.html). In any case, [this post](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/smallchanges/2007-12-18#disqus_thread) is an explanation of the problem I was having and also a solution using xquery.